# php $GLOBALS lanza warning al intentar hacer count()

Tags: php, variables-globales, count

En php 7.4 estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

he creado un array:

```
$example_array = [
    'null'         => null,
    'null_text'    => 'null',
];
```

y lo he casteado en un objeto:

```
$example_array = (object) $example_array;
```

Luego dentro de un Metodo en intentado verificar cuantos elementos tiene con `count()`:

```
class Output_Handler
{
    public function output($var_name)
    {
        $data            = $GLOBALS[$var_name];
        $count           = count($data);
        $type            = gettype($data);
        echo $count.' '.$type;
    }
}

$output        = new Output_Handler();
$output->output('example_array');
```

y el resultado:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
> implements Countable in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\t5\BOH-Basic-Output-Handler\src\Output_Handler.php
> on line 10

> 1 object

no puedo dejar de usar `GLOBALS` por que el método esta preparado para recibir el nombre de la variable y después usar los datos.

Comment: Estás convirtiendo el arreglo en un objeto [con clase _stdClass_](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) que, según el manual, [no es "contable"](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-countable.php#example-6356). En todo caso, podrías intentar contar las propiedades con [get_object_vars()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: gracias @Triby voy a verificar eso; tambien dice que puedo hacer que el objeto sea una instancia de contable pero no se como se hace exactamente Xd

Comment: Necesitas crear una clase que implemente [Countable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.countable.php). En los comentarios del manual puede haber algunos ejemplos.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiquemos:

- Lo que tienes inicialmente es un *array* y no un *objeto*
- Luego haces un *cast* para pasar ese array a un objeto
- Luego en el listado de [cambios incompatibles en PHP 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration72.incompatible.php), nos indica que:

  - [Obtendrás *una advertencia*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types) cuando se traten de contabilizar tipos que no son contables, esto incluye a todos los objetos que no implementen la interfaz `Countable`

Para el punto anterior, si revisas al hacer esto:

```
$example_array = (object)[
                    
                        'null'         => null,
                        'null_text'    => 'null',    
                ];


var_dump(is_countable($example_array));
```

Te dará como salida:

> bool(false)

Ya que precisamente estás obteniendo uno de los tipos de datos que [no pueden ser contabilizados](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-countable.php#refsect1-function.is-countable-description)

- Por otro lado no logro identificar que utilidad real tiene en tu muestra de código el uso de *`$_GLOBALS`* cuando la misma esta destinada a obtener [*la referencia de las variables disponibles en el ámbito global*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.globals.php) ya que debería bastar con indicar el parámetro que recibe el método en su declaración y posterior por medio del objeto instanciado cuando accedes a dicho método pasarle como argumento el objeto o array a evaluar y tratar de contabilizar.

Entonces el código que expones, debería alcanzar con:

- Remover el uso de `$_GLOBALS`
- Cuando trates de imprimir el conteo de elementos del objeto, realiza un cast que lo traiga de regreso a la estructura de un *array*

  - El punto anterior podría depender de la *complejidad* de la estructura del objeto, puede incluso ser necesario algo de *recursividad* para que se transforme un objeto mas complejo en un array

Dejo lo siguiente solo como una **muy pequeña referencia**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

$example_array = [
    'null'         => null,
    'null_text'    => 'null',
];

class Algo
{
    public function contador($arrayIngresado): int
    {
        return count($arrayIngresado);
    }
}

echo (new Algo())->contador($example_array).PHP_EOL;

var_dump($example_array);

echo (new Algo())->contador((array)$example_array).PHP_EOL;
```

Con esta salida:

```
2
array(2) {
  ["null"]=>
  NULL
  ["null_text"]=>
  string(4) "null"
}
2
```

> Claramente esta respuesta no pretende ser una solución absoluta y debería darse la oportunidad de recibir otras **soluciones mas completas**

Comment: si me equivoque al momento de escribir el post es un array y lo casteo a objeto... necesuto usar GLobals ya que el objetivo de la funcion es recibir el nombre de la variable y no la variable como tal, peroooo dentro de la misma tambien requiero acceder a sus datos... entonces uso GLOBALS

Comment: partiendo que un objeto es iterable entonces como se cuantos propiedades tiene???

Comment: Ya entendí mejor tu código, remuevo esta respuesta

Comment: modificala va en buen camino me dio ideas XD